# Get data from iPhone in DFU mode, by having all the passwords

Tags: iphone, ios, data-recovery

I have and iPhone 7 in DFU mode, It is blocked during normal use.

The iPhone had iOS 11.4, after it crashed following the instructions I tried to update it to iOS 13, but the update didn't go well.

It is now completely locked in DFU mode

Having all the passwords and a one year old backup, I don't want to lose the data from recent changes.

Can I recover the data from a device in this state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word, no. The data on your device is, as you know, permanently encrypted. And is decrypted, when in use, partially by using your lock code. As far as I know, and I am fairly certain of this, there is no known mechanism for decrypting the data off-device, and you cannot move the data off device either because there is no way to move the data off while in DFU mode. And they do not provide any way to decrypt the data using the lock code in any other cicumstances than what happens in a full normal boot.

So, in DFU mode, there is no way to decrypt the data on-device, and no mechanism for moving the data off-device.